# How to setup emacs for Google Java Style

Tags: java, emacs

I am surprised, but after searching, I cannot find an emacs configuration that I can use to have emacs follow [Google Java Style](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html).

If there is such a configuration already available I would appreciate links to it.

Otherwise, how would I create such a configuration?

UPDATE:

The most basic thing I would like to learn : what customization variables do I set to get [2 spaces for block indentation](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.2-block-indentation) and [4 spaces for continuation lines](http://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.5.2-line-wrapping-indent)?

Comment: Good question. And not just Google Java style, but the most popular Java styles in general. Emacs defaults to its `java-style`, which is pretty atypical, I think (and it offers no other styles to choose from, out of the box).

Answer (score 2):

Put https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/google-c-style.el on your load path, such as in `~/.emacs.d/`.

Then, in your Emacs init file, add:

```
;; Also works for Java.
(autoload 'google-set-c-style "google-c-style")
(autoload 'google-make-newline-indent "google-c-style")
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-set-c-style)
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook 'google-make-newline-indent)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own style and apply it using "c-set-style". Below is how I defined my own C style and set it. Defining a style for java is the same. And note that, java is somehow regarded as a "submode" of C, therefore, all the variables and functions start with "c-".

```
;;; c mode configuration
(defconst lgfang-c-style
  '((c-tab-always-indent        . t)
    (c-basic-offset . 4)
    (c-ignore-auto-fill . nil)
    (c-comment-only-line-offset . (0 . 0))
    (c-hanging-braces-alist     . ((substatement-open after before)
                                   (brace-list-open)))
    (c-hanging-colons-alist     . ((member-init-intro before)
                                   (inher-intro)
                                   (case-label after)
                                   (label after)
                                   (access-label after)))
    (c-cleanup-list             . (scope-operator
                                   empty-defun-braces
                                   defun-close-semi))
    (c-offsets-alist . ((knr-argdecl-intro . 5)
                        (arglist-intro . +)
                        (arglist-close . c-lineup-close-paren)
                        (inclass . +)
                        (member-init-intro . +)
                        (statement-block-intro . +)
                        (defun-block-intro . +)
                        (substatement-open . 0)
                        (label . 0)
                        (statement-case-open . +)
                        (statement-case-intro . +)
                        (case-label . 0)
                        (statement-cont . c-lineup-math)
                        (inline-open . 0)
                        (brace-list-open . +)
                        (topmost-intro-cont . 0)
                        (c . 1) ; "c" for continue of comment, not "c
                                ; programming language"
                        ))
    (c-special-indent-hook . c-gnu-impose-minimum)
    (c-block-comment-prefix . "lgf: ")
    (c-comment-prefix-regexp . ((awk-mode . "#+(lgf: )?")
                                (other ."lgf: \\|//+\\|\\**")))
    ;; go to this file and test if c block comments works
    ;; [[file:./patches/comments-test.c]]
    (c-echo-syntactic-information-p . t))
  "lgfang's C Programming Style")
(c-add-style "lgfang" lgfang-c-style nil)

(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-style "lgfang")
            (c-toggle-hungry-state 1)
            (hs-minor-mode 1)
            (turn-on-cwarn-mode)
            ;; (eldoc-mode 1)
            ))
```

Comment: thanks - that's kind of what I was looking for.  What variables do I set to get:  2 spaces for newlines in a block, and 4 spaces for long lines that I split into two? (see my update to the original question).

Comment: Please refer to emacs manual (info "(ccmode)Styles") for details. One tip I'd like to offer is:

open a java file, at every point where you want to change the indentation, press "tab" and see what shows up on the mini-buffer

Comment: That tip really helps!

Answer (score -1):

If you download https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/google-c-style.el (as mernst suggests), you can put the style right into your project and enable it with a .dir-locals.el file.

1. Download the file and put it into ${project}/emacs/google-c-style.el
2. Create a file ${project}/.dir-locals.el and put into it:

```
((java-mode . ((eval . (progn
                        (add-to-list 'load-path (concat (vc-root-dir) "emacs"))
                        (require 'google-c-style)
                        (google-set-c-style)
                        (google-make-newline-indent))))))
```